# Spark Event log directory

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am using PySpark (standalone without hadoop etc) and calling my pyspark jobs below and it works fine:

```
PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3 JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre" SPARK_HOME=~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark spark-submit job.py --master local
```

The History Server is running however I am trying to configure the Spark History Server to read the correct directory. The settings I have configured are in /pyspark/conf/spark-env.sh:

```
....
SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS="$SPARK_HISTORY_OPTS -Dspark.eventLog.enabled=true -Dspark.eventLog.dir=/home/Documents/Junk/logs/ -Dspark.history.fs.logDirectory=/home/Documents/Junk/logs"
....
```

But when I run jobs, this directory is empty (logs not writing to this directory)

Am I specifying the directory addresses correctly? (thes are local addresses in my file system)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get it working, do the following. Do not use spark-env.sh and instead edit the conf/spark-defaults.conf file with the following, note the file:// prefix.

```
spark.eventLog.enabled           true
spark.eventLog.dir             file:///home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/logs
spark.history.fs.logDirectory   file:///home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/logs
```